# Blender adds Armature name to Actions name when exporting FBX

Tags: armature, export, .fbx, actions

[image]

When I export an animated FBX with different Actions in it, Blender renames the Actions like this (Armature name 2x before the action name). I tried renaming the Actions directly in the Blender file menu, but whenever I export the fbxs, those "Armatures" are added to the Actions name.

This doesn't cause any issue, it's just driving me mad and I didn't find anything about it on the internet

Answer (score 0):

Typicaly there can be a lot of animations in one file, and nobody knows relationships beetween animations and objects. To sort out you may put on all animations in NLA then in Export setting checkmark export NLA, disabling Export all actions:

[image]